# How to store some value to use in entire project in alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am developing Alexa music app and it is working like this.
I am asking Alexa to play music for a artist say it lady gaga. I am fetching the name and passing it to my api and getting 10 songs in response.
Now I am passing first song to `InetentRequest` and playing the song.

Now i am looking for `AudioPlayer.PlaybackNearlyFinished` request form alexa to enque the second song. But the issue is I am unable to get the name of artist here to play song. So is there anyway to store the name of artist somewhere and use it in the project wherever i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to store session data like that is in the session attributes of the response.

When you create a response object you put whatever data you want in the 'sessionAttributes' object.  If you are using an SDK it will probably have a function for this.

When you receive the next intent in the same Alexa session it will have your data in 'session.attributes' of the event.

The [docs](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interface-reference) refer to your data as 'A map of key-value pairs' but I find that you can put anything you want in there as long as the top-level is an object and not an array.

Comment: is it mandatory that the shouldEndSession for response should be false.. because i am keeping it true so that next song would play immediately

Comment: I think that would be a problem.  Those attributes are associated with the Alexa session and setting shouldEndSession to true will end the session.  So, even assuming that the user continues their interaction with your skill, it will be a new sessionId and I believe that your session attributes will be gone.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the issue that is causing you to do this (keeping shouldEndSession as true) but I would encourage you to find another solution to that because keeping shouldEndSession as true is unusual and will have side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not storing the artist in the session and persisting it to the next song, I think you may need to find some way to use the MusicRecording intent in your skill.

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/built-in-intent-ref/musicrecording-intents

Comment: That's the question, how do i suppose to store the artist and fetch it?

Comment: When you invoke the intent to play music by an artist, that artist is a slot to the intent or some custom value being passed as part of the call to the AudioPlayer.  You would store it in the session by adding a custom attribute and value.  In Python, it might look like this:

`artist = intent['slots']['Artist']['value']
session_attributes = {"currentArtist" : artist}`